# Azure DevOps pipeline for running processes

Tags: c#, .net, windows, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm currently working on a project that has no CI/CD, everything is done by manually copying!
I have a .Net project that basically runs as a service on my server, right now with the manual copy process I have to kill the job, and copy the new dll's or exe's and restart, otherwise I'd get an error that the process is running and deleting/replacing it is not possible.

What's going to happen when using Azure DevOps pipeline? Am I going to have the same issue? I can't find much regarding this online.

Comment: If you need to replace an executable image while it is mapped into a process, then it doesn't matter who is going to attempt to replace it. All attempts will fail for the same reason. Now clearly, your CD procedure doesn't merely copy files around. Copying files doesn't magically launch processes. Since you avoided talking about that part there's literally nothing we can do to help.

Comment: I'm confused on what I avoided talking about. Well the way my program works is all I need to do is literally copy some new dlls and I don't have to do anything after that! So if I have a text file open and I pull a new version of that text file using git it won't fail it will actually tell the user to reload because the file has changed, but if I have a text file open and try to manually copy a different version of that text file in place of it, windows will complain as "a user has it open" or "process is in use" so I was just wondering what will the Azure DevOps pipeline will do in this case

Comment: I doubt that Azure DevOps has any text editors open, so I'm confused as to what scenario you have in mind.

Comment: this was just a random example. I just want to know if Azure's copy works the same way as windows or works like the way git does... Now I'm confused on what's happening here, maybe I'm not understanding the basic fundamentals here

Comment: Regardless of who is copying a file, it will ultimately have to call into the OS, such as one of the [CopyFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-copyfile) implementations. It doesn't matter whether Azure does this, or Git, or some random other program. Ultimately, it's the OS that decides whether that operation can be performed or not.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the following links' information, summarizing, CI/CD tools are designed to automate all the required actions that need to be executed to deploy new versions of your code/apps (among other objectives). You are manually executing those actions right now, and CI/CD is going to do it on behalf of you. Most of the Cloud solutions for CI/CD are designed to run, avoiding any impact in the application's availability. Take a look in the following links, the first one for the root concept and the second one mostly inside Azure Dev Ops:

[Continuous integration and continuous delivery explained](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3271126/what-is-cicd-continuous-integration-and-continuous-delivery-explained.html)
[Design a CI/CD pipeline using Azure DevOps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/example-scenario/apps/devops-dotnet-webapp)

Comment: Unfortunately none of this answers the question to if another user has the file open or the process is running would I be able to just use the copy (probably this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) to just copy and have the process just reload after copy or if I would encounter an error saying the operation is not permitted because the process is running (that's what happens when you manually try to do it so you have to stop the process, copy the new files and restart)

Comment: Those policies can be set up by you, for example, when to do it, under which circumstances not to stop and/or restart the process, the timing, etc. The pipeline, at least in Microsoft's case, is design by you and once in execution, it is going to figure out how to run CI/CD accomplishing with your settings and conditions.

Comment: So I'm mostly asking this because the way my program works is all I need to do is literally copy some new dlls and I don't have to do anything after that! So if I have a text file open and I pull a new version of that text file using git it won't fail it will actually tell the user to reload because the file has changed, but if I have a text file open and try to manually copy a different version of that text file in place of it, windows will complain as "a user has it open" or "process is in use" so I was just wondering what will the Azure DevOps pipeline will do in this case